# Python piped subprocess hanging after join

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Hopefully this is a fairly easy question to answer.  I am trying to constantly send an array of data to a worker process while my program is executing.  The issue is that, when I attempt to join the thread, the program just hangs.

I'd thought that perhaps the worker terminated and I didn't need to `join`, however when I remove the call to `join` my program hangs at the end.

Here is a snippet of my code.  I am attempting to circumvent large pickling operations by using a worker in this manner, as I'd previously run into overhead issues with a Queue object.

```
# Outside of the class definition if that matters here...
def RunTimeWorker(conn, timestep, total_timesteps):
  print "Start worker", timestep, total_timesteps
  while (timestep < total_timesteps):
    data = conn.recv()
    timestep = data[0]
    print timestep, "DATA [" + str(data)
 conn.close()
 print "End worker"
```

And the class method calling it:

```
def Execute(self):
  parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
  p = Process(target=RunTimeTestingWorker,args=(child_conn,0,300))
  p.start()

  for timestep in xrange(300):
    ... 
    # Send required data over to worker
    toProcessArr = [timestep,300,
       # trace data
       ...,...]
    parent_conn.send(toProcessArr)
    ...
  p.join # program hangs here

  #p.join  -- program will hang at end if join is commented
```

Here my timestep is updating successfully...

```
Start worker 0 300
0 DATA [[0, 300, ...]
1 DATA [[1, 300, ...]
2 DATA [[2, 300, ...]
...
299 DATA [[299, 300, ...] # max timesteps are 300
```

---

**Edit**

As David so rightly pointed out, this was a stupid error on my part.  However, his comment regarding adding a sentinel is highly valuable.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand, but stdout/stderr shouldn't factor in here.  I simply want to pipe some data to a subprocess.

Comment: @Lattyware I think you may be confusing `multiprocessing` with `subprocess`?

Comment: I was attempting to follow the [Pipe example here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your worker is waiting on `timestep < total_timesteps`, where `total_timesteps = 300` but `timestep = 299` (because `timestep` is in `xrange(300)` which is 0..299).

A better pattern here is to send some kind of sentinel value when processing is done. For example, changing the worker to:

```
while True:
    data = con.recv()
    if data == "DONE":
        break
```

Then on the producer:

```
parent_conn.send("DONE")
p.join()
```

Comment: I feel like I should delete this question because....you are exactly right.  Ha...good catch.

Comment: @espais Definitely don't delete - others may well have the same problem and this will help them. Also, you'd be denying David his all-important internet points for catching it ;)